# Why does Visual Studio grow in memory up to 2gb?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (with update 2) on Windows 7. When I have it open, even if I never do any debugging and I'm only editing files, devenv.exe will start using more and more and more memory. I can watch it grow in task manager until it's up to like 2.2GB. This is crazy.

I've turned off 'Enable full solution analysis.' I've turned off animations. I've disabled 'track changes' for text editor. I've disabled source control. I'm not using codelense or resharper...and I still have this crazy memory usage problem.

(edit) Solution: Uninstalling McAfee eliminated the problem.

Comment: Unless it were something like "Visual Studio has trouble with large F# files" here's probably no way for SO users to narrow down the causes. We don't have the source except for some CLR bits, and don't have internal visibility into where devenv.exe is using RAM!

Comment: analyze the memory usage grow with ETW: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc. But install the WIn10 SDK/WPT (also works for Win7) and run **wpr -start DotNET -start VirtualAllocation** now capture 2 minutes of the grow, go back to cmd and run this **wpr -stop C:\temp\result.etl** Now analyze the ETL with WPA as shown in the video

Comment: thanks, it might take me a while to figure out how to get wpr to work, as I am current getting this error "The system cannot find the file specified. Error code: 0x80070002" when I run "wpr -start DotNET -start VirtualAllocation"

Comment: use full path for WPR: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe"  -start DotNET -start VirtualAllocation. This works fine. Maybe you have the older 8.1 version in your path

Comment: I sent Microsoft a dump via "Report a Problem" and one of their guys analyzed it, see here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7082#issuecomment-226016022

Comment: I uninstalled McAfee today, and this problem seems to have disappeared. I should have known.

Comment: ok, post your "fix" as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Uninstalling McAfee eliminated the problem.